# Doubt in using "on which" in a sentence

Tags: phrase-usage

I have doubt in using the "on which" phrase. Is the sentence below correct, as I have to write this sentence as part of research interest in my academic resume?

> I’ve developed interests in the device development and characterizations, on which I have done my master research project.

Comment: It could be 'on which' or even 'in which'.  Why do you think it could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence gives rise to a couple of questions.

It refers to **in the device development**. This only makes sense if you have already referred to the device concerned as it implies a specific device.

If you are talking about devices in general, you would need to say **in device development**, without **the**.

If by **master research project** you mean a research project for a master's degree, you need to change it to **my master's (degree) research project**.

So, you probably mean one of the two following statements:

> I have developed interests in (the) device development and characterisations, on which I have done my master's research project.

This means that your interests are in the development and characterisations, either of **the** device concerned - or devices in general (if you omit **the**)

> I have developed interests in the development and characterisations of the device on which I have done my master's research project.

This means that you are interested in the properties of the device concerned - which you need to have specified.

Comment: I need to write this sentence in research interest section of my cv as I am applying for PhD positions.

Comment: Exactly what was your master's research project? It sounds a bit strange to say that you developed interests in aspects of your master's research project. Surely you had those interests before you did your master's degree.

Comment: I developed a capacitor device in my master's research project. I also did some characterizations (microscopy, spectroscopy), as part of the device development, in my project. The PhD position says I need to have some experience in device development and characterizations.

Comment: I suggest:  **In my master's research project, I developed a capacitor device, a project that required microscopy and spectroscopy characterisations among others.** That sums it up. You could add that the device or accompanying research has proved valuable in some respect - if this is the case. Be as specific as possible.

Comment: Hi Ronald. Thanks for helping me. I generally write 3 sentences in the research section (on top of the CV).    " (1) I have spent five years of study in the field of Materials Science following my research interests.
(2) I’ve developed interests in device development and characterizations on which I have done my master’s research project.
(3) I would love to advance my understanding of the period further, through PhD study with an expert at a remarkable institution."
I have doubt in the 2nd sentence, whether it is correct grammatically.

Comment: Rishab. I should say that we are not meant to give style advice. Your statement is fine, although I would suggest **a leading institution** rather than a **remarkable one.** Good luck.